# Is there a notion of "multiplicative averaging"?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

We can average $a,b\in \mathbb{R}$ by the simple calculation

$$\frac{a+b}{2}$$

The above is the usual average. Now, I wonder if a notion for "multiplicative average" exists, where we take ($a,b>0$)

$$\sqrt{a b}$$

Clearly, this is nothing like the actual average, but it seems to me that such an operation might be useful in a similar fashion as the average. Does it exist in some context? And if yes, how is it called properly?

Comment: It is called "the geometric mean". See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inequality_of_arithmetic_and_geometric_mean.

Comment: +1 for rediscovering this idea. Do check the wikipedia page.

Comment: @user70476 The provided link has a lot of lengthy stuff. A very simple property of the geometric mean is that if given a rectangle with dimensions $a$ and $b$, the formula gives you a square that has the same area as the rectangle. The area of this square is then $ab$ and the sides of the square follow by taking the squareroot. This is usually how geometric mean is introduced at high school geometry level. There are of course lots of other applications of the geometric mean too.

Comment: @imranfat Thank you! This was a very intuitive explanation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is called a geometric mean. The average you already know is called an arithmetic mean.

Answer (score 2):

There are connections of the geometric mean to the arithmetic mean. If $(a_j)_{j=0}^{m-1}$ are positive reals and $a$ their geometric mean, then $\log a$ is the arithmetic mean of $(\log a_j)_{j=0}^{m-1}$, or
$$  \log a = \frac1m\sum_{j=0}^{m-1} \log a_j $$